# How to get count of no. of documents available in MongoDb using NodeJs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I am trying to get number of documents available in my collection using NodeJS. I am getting number successfully in console but it is not sending response and showing below error:

> RangeError [ERR_HTTP_INVALID_STATUS_CODE]: Invalid status code: 10
>   at ServerResponse.writeHead (_http_server.js:246:11)
>   at ServerResponse._implicitHeader (_http_server.js:237:8)
>   at ServerResponse.end (_http_outgoing.js:720:10)
>   at ServerResponse.send (D:\Backend\aamku_con_backend\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:221:10)
>   at D:\Backend\aamku_con_backend\routes\dealerCount.js:29:50
>   at executeCallback (D:\Backend\aamku_con_backend\node_modules\mongodb\lib\operations\execute_operation.js:74:5)
>   at callbackWithRetry (D:\Backend\aamku_con_backend\node_modules\mongodb\lib\operations\execute_operation.js:122:14)
>   at D:\Backend\aamku_con_backend\node_modules\mongodb\lib\operations\count_documents.js:36:7
>   at D:\Backend\aamku_con_backend\node_modules\mongodb\lib\operations\command_v2.js:90:9
>   at D:\Backend\aamku_con_backend\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connection_pool.js:308:13 {
>   code: 'ERR_HTTP_INVALID_STATUS_CODE'

Below is my code:

```
router.get("/dealerCount", (req, res) => {        
  MongoClient.connect(dburl,{ useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true },
    (err, client) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log("Error", err);
      } else {
        const coll = client.db("Mydb").collection("Dealers");

        coll.countDocuments(function(err, resp) {
          if (err) {
            console.log("Error", err);
          } else {
            console.log(resp);
            res.send(resp);
          }
        });
      }
    }
  );
});
```

Someone please let me know how can I get total count in response. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is `res.send(resp);` line. It is making express think that you are sending a integer which is not allowed. Replace that with this

```
res.send({"value": resp});

OR

res.send(resp.toString());
```

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to convert it into string now its working fine.